# How to call count operation of MongoDB query on JMeter using groovy?

Tags: mongodb, groovy, jmeter

I have a query as below which is working on mongoDB

I need to execute this query in JMeter to get the objects count. Please note I am using Groovy script to execute the same.

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({ $or: [ {"Service" :"AAA"}, {ServerName : "BBB"} ],
   "ConnectionID" : "AAAA445789",
       "CDDval" : "AGB"
});

Below is the code i am running in groovy and not giving the expected result like Mongodb query above.it is giving error javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:


try {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collectionName");

     Document result = collection.find("uuid" ,"{$or : [

    {"Service": "AAA"},
    {ServerName : "BBB"}    
    ],

     "ConnectionID" : "AAAA445789",
     "CDDval" : "AGB"


     "}).first;


     vars.put("uuid", result.get("uuid").toString());

     return "uuid=" + result.get("uuid") + " found";

}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}

I have tried the using JMeter Groovy 2.4.13 but not getting correct respose, below is the code
```

Comment: What is the issue/problem? It will be easy for others to help, if you share what have you done or tried till now.